# UIImagePickerController capture full screen on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController class to capture image from camera.

When is captured, I save the picture on disk. After that I use imageWithContentsOfFile method to load this image as background of the main screen.

The problem is that when I load the picture appears 2 white bands on top & bottom of the view.

My question is how can I take a picture with 320X480px of size in order to load it full screen?

Thanks.

--EDIT--

The originalImage when is captured sizes this:

```
INFO -> Captured Image Size W:480.000000 H:640.000000
```

How can I get the image directly 320X480px?

Thanks.

Comment: @NemeSys when u captured image then save as image@2x.png and when u passed to background then use image.png. because 640*960 used for retina display and 320*480 used for normal display. or u can resize image.

Comment: Hi ios! Thanks for the response, but If I understand, the image recently captured without any transform sizes 480 X 640 px. I have to save it as @2x and without? But the resolution must be 640X960 why I'm getting 480 x 640?

Comment: Hi Raj!, thanks 4 the response. But If I resize the image I'll loss the aspect ratio (this not possible). How can I get an image with the same size as appears in capture preview? Full portrait screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you get white bands because you've got the content mode of the `UIImageView` you're displaying it in set to `UIViewContentModeAspectFit` which means resize the image, maintaining aspect so that it you can see the entire image. If you set the content mode to `UIViewContentModeAspectFill` it'll do what you want.

The reason for this discrepancy is that the aspect ratio of the screen (2:3) is not the same as the aspect ratio of the images that come from the camera (3:4).

Comment: Solved. The image is a little bigger as in preview, but make the work.